# Xpath for TR and TD tags

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

[image]

Hi everyone,

I need to get integer value and compare it with another value in different tag. what is the xpath for this.How can i get this. I have attached a screeshot

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following：

```
//div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[@class='hoverElement']/a
```

or

```
//a[contains(@class,'MediumSmallPopup-Small')]
```

Either way, you should be able to locate element `a`

Answer (score 2):

Please try this

```
WebElement e = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[@class='hoverElement']/a"));
System.out.println("getText() " + e.getText());
```

In "e" you can get the actual value "2,053" the one that you you are looking for.

Comment: You might want to explain what this piece of code does and why you think this will solve he problem.

Comment: In "e" he can get the actual value "2,053" what he is looking for.

Comment: See, now you are suppose to add that information in the answer itself.

Comment: Please check now @Saurabh

Answer (score 2):

Getting the xpath for that is a bit more troublesome without seeing the html for the entire table and here's why:

1. you have multiple `tr` tags that have the same class with the row that you need: `class="h1 rowHighlight"`. Since the other rows are not expanded, the cells inside (`td` tags) may have the same the same classes with the cell that you need.
2. going forward, in the row that you need there is only a single cell with `class="hoverElement"` but having in mind #1, the same may be present in other rows, especially since there are no `id`'s and classes are used for a more general purpose.

The bullet-points, #1 and #2 are an assumption on the class names used in your HTML, that leads me to think that is some kind of financing application with different information for a specific account that may be displayed by hours, days, weeks, etc, leading to multiple links (`a` tags) in your table.

But because of this, those `a` tags can be your "friend" here so your best guess would be a combination of whatever you hope to have unique there, something like:

```
.//tr[@class='h1 rowHighligh']/td[@class='hoverElement']/a[contains(@class,'MediumSmallPopup-Small')]
```

You can also make use of the `a` tag:

```
.//tr[@class='h1 rowHighligh']/td[@class='hoverElement']/a[@href='your_link_from_the_page']
```

Again, if this still finds more than one element, you can combine the `a` tag's `class` and `href` attributes, especially since the `class` attribute is a compound one:

```
.//tr[@class='h1 rowHighligh']/td[@class='hoverElement']/a[contains(@class,'MediumSmallPopup-Small') and contains(@class,'cboxElement') and contains(@class,'firepath-matching-node') and @href='your_link_from_the_page']
```

Note that this is not different than saying
`@class='MediumSmallPopup-Small cboxElement firepath-matching-node' and @href='your_link_from_the_page'` but I've separated only for the case when you may have other `a` tags with the same conpund `class` and the same `href` (which is highly unlikely).